Rails API application - JWT authentication with Refresh token
I am trying to implement refresh token route in my existing Rails API application. JWT authentication should work the same way in any programming language or framework but in my case it's Rails.
Application is using jwt gem for encoding and decoding tokens. Devise is not used in this case and I would like to avoid it. There are two custom routes for login and logout and the main thing used in them is JWT.encode and JWT.decode
And as far as my understanding goes (please correct me if i am wrong) once token is generated via JWT.encode and sent to frontend (in this case ReactJS) that token will be kept on the client side and sent in each request as Bearer Token.
Each token that is created has expiration time that we can send as parameter to JWT.encode method as part of the payload.
def encode(payload, key, algorithm = 'HS256', header_fields = {})
  Encode.new(payload: payload,
             key: key,
             algorithm: algorithm,
             headers: header_fields).segments
end

More about JWT in general, it consists of three parts:

Header: contains information about token including what algorithm is used for signing.

Payload: contains data that will be kept in the token (usually user uuid and role)

Signature: this is where it get's interesting :) Signature is made of
HMACSHA256( base64UrlEncode(header) + "." + base64UrlEncode(payload), secret_key)


What this means is that strings from encoded headers and payload are merged together with secret_key to create a HASH. This hash will be the same only if data in the token is not changed and the key is correct. If someone changes something in the payload (or does not have the key which is usually kept in the safe place), signature will be different and validation will fail.
Of course if someone steals your token he can impersonate you but there is nothing we can do about it.
If everything above is correct how would we implement refresh token route to this?
Refresh token route "flow" would be if API request validation fails with let's say status 403 there will be a callback function on frontend that will call refresh token route to get a new token and than call the same API that previously failed.
My question is, what would be the best way to organize this on the backend side. Refresh token is suppost to be generated after JWT.encode and returned with the access token to frontend.
That means that we need to have this data in our database so that we can compare refresh token with it's expiry date, access token that goes with it etc.
Before Rails i used Laravel and they have Passport package for this that has these columns in refresh_tokens table

id
access_token_id: which in this case would need to be the access token itself? Since jwt gem does not keep any of it's data in the
database and we don't actually have another tables for access tokens
revoked (boolean): basically a column that would indicate is this token renewed or not
expiry_at: when does refresh token actually expires and user needs to login again
refresh_token: i guess we need to add this column to this table since we need a way to compare access and refresh tokens (this
column does not exist in Laravel Passport)
timestamps

Would it make sense and is it safe to create the same structure in my current database and implement the flow i mentioned above? And what would be the best way to create refresh token?
It should have the longer lifespan than the access token but it shouldn't have the same access rights.
One idea that i have is to use the same JWT.encode but with additional data in the payload like this
access_token = JWT.encode({user_uuid: user.uuid, role: user.role, type: 'access', exp: 1.hour.to_id})
refresh_token = JWT.encode({user_uuid: user.uuid, role: user.role, type: 'refresh', exp: 3.days.to_i})
And than in the API middleware validation we also check whether user sent access or refresh token.

Does any of this make any sense and do you have any other suggestions?

"does any of this make any sense" – no offense, but if you are that unsure, you might want to do some more research before implementing your own auth workflow.

Non taken, i did my fair share of research and that's why i am asking here. It looks like there is not some "defined" way to do this, usually main focus is on the access token and there are many libraries for it. But when it comes to refresh token story is different and i am trying to make to best possible solution for this.

In general, both token types are alike. They have signatures for validation and you can embed an exp claim for expiry. What is different is its purpose: you use a refresh token to get a new access token and for nothing else. That said, for a very basic workflow, you don't need to store anything in a database. That is only needed if you want to keep track of tokens, want to know which access tokens were requested by which refresh token, to revoke tokens (needs an additional check) or for refresh token rotation

... however all those topics are too much for a SO answer which makes your question seem a little too broad. I'd start with a simple (easy to understand) workflow and make it more complex step by step as your requirements change. Don't just copy another's library database structure without understanding why.

JWT is just a way to send a Base64 encoded piece of JSON signed. It is not an authentication mechanism. You can use JWT in an OAuth flow. There is no need to use Devise for this indeed, but the OAuth gem might help you structure that flow a bit more.
